# how to 301 redirect from a plugin folder

Tags: seo, redirect, noindex

Some how google indexed a directory inside one of the plugins I use.  I cannot figure out how to set a 301 redirect from the indexed path to the home page.  has anyone else seen or dealt with this?

here is what google indexed. I have replace all personal information with generic.

http://www.domainname.com/wp-own-dir/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name-here/directory-in-plugin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give an noindex in your robots.txt - `Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/` and dont access the wp-content/plugins folder; also you can add an 301 redirect in your WP install via Plugin or with an extra in the htaccess